# Display enum string in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework

I am using an ENUM class within my model.  I need to display the associated string in a grid.

```
public enum FileStatus
{
    New = 1,
    Working = 2,
    Competed = 3
}
```

The model -

```
public class FileInformation
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String RFQ { get; set; }
    public String FileName { get; set; }
    public String CustomerName { get; set; }
    public FileType FileTypeId { get; set; }
    public FileStatus FileStatusId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public String CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public String ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FileStatus> FileStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FileType> FileType { get; set; }

    private FileInformation()
    {
        Id = SequentialGuid.Create(SequentialGuidType.SequentialAtEnd);
    }
```

The HTML view which is displaying the result -

```
<td>{{files.fileStatusId}}</td>
```

Right now the output in the table is a 1 which is correct but I need to display the text "New".  What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using JSON.Net to send your objects to angularjs, then you can simply use `StringEnumConverter` to serialize the value as string instead of an int.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public FileType FileTypeId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to have your client side *know* the enum type by having those enums in the client as well.

It might sound tedious and horrible to maintain, especially if you think about all the enums you have in the system. And it is!

That's why I'll suggest you look at T4 Template, and use that with custom attributes on your enums in a way that will **automatically** build your enums and add them to the client on builds/deploys. This way you'll never have to worry about this.

**What do you get at the end ?**

You'll have the following Javascript code which will help you switch between text and values of enums:

```
var FileStatus;
(function (FileStatus) {
    FileStatus[FileStatus["New"] = 1] = "New";
    FileStatus[FileStatus["Working"] = 2] = "Working";
    FileStatus[FileStatus["Competed"] = 3] = "Competed";
})(FileStatus || (FileStatus = {}));
```

This way you get:

```
FileStatus[1]; // "New"
FileStatus["New"]; // 1
```